# What happens to up and down votes before you have the privilege to cast such votes?

Tags: support, voting, undo

At 1 reputation you have neither the privilege of upvoting nor the privilege of downvoting. If you try it anyway, you get some message from the system, from which I understood that your vote is saved until the moment you get the relevant voting privilege and then (retro-actively?) cast. Perhaps I am just reading into it though and the attempted vote is instead ignored?

What actually happens to such prematurely attempted votes? And if they are indeed held until you get the relevant privilege, can you undo them?